# Understanding Intersection of Two Planes

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, plane-geometry

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this equation (2+s-3t, -1-2s+t, 3-t) (s,t∈R)

Supposedly this is the intersection of two planes, however it seems to me that this is still an equation for a plane.

Question: So does that mean that the original planes are actually just coincident?

Additionally, in the z bracket, why is there no s value, and what does that mean?

~Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector can be written 
$$\begin {pmatrix}2 \\-1\\ 3
\end {pmatrix} + s \begin {pmatrix}1\\-2\\ 0
\end {pmatrix} + t \begin {pmatrix}-3\\1\\ -1
\end {pmatrix} 
$$ which does represent a plane. The first vector represents a point on the plane and the other 2 vectors form a basis for the plane and different values of the parameters $s$ and $t$ take you to different points in the plane. 
It does not matter that $s$ does not appear in the $z$ component.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!